# three.js obj/mtl work in safari, but not work in chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try the three.js obj/mtl loader, but it not always render correct.

In sarafi it works correct, but in chrome/firefox ite render to black.

My environment:

OS: OSX Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0
Chrome: 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
Safari: 10.0.2 (12602.3.12.0.1)

I start the local server use 
`http://localhost/threejs_demo.html`
to visit the html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                canvas: document.getElementById('mainCanvas')
            });
            renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF); // black

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 400 / 300, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(150, 150, 150);
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            scene.add(camera);

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            var mesh = null;
            mtlLoader.setPath( 'js/Vanille/' );
            mtlLoader.load('vanille_obj.mtl', function(materials) {
                materials.preload();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setPath( 'js/Vanille/' );
                    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                    objLoader.load('vanille_obj.obj', function ( object ) {
                        mesh = object;
                        scene.add(object);
                    });
                },1000);
            });

            var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
            scene.add(light);

            function draw() {
                if (mesh) {
                    mesh.rotation.y = (mesh.rotation.y + 0.01) % (Math.PI * 2);
                }
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            setInterval(draw, 20);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<canvas id="mainCanvas" width="800px" height="600px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

render result in chrome/firefox

[image: render result in chrome/firefox]

render result in safari

[image: render result in safari]

Comment: What is the texture size, is it power-of-two? If not, does rescaling to power-of-two in a drawing program have any effect on the issue?

Comment: Chrome has more severe security sandbox restrictions on 127.0.01. make the first line in your init: THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

Comment: If you're running locally use [a simpler server](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/webgl/2605/getting-started-with-webgl/8648/installation-or-setup#t=201703310248295121375). Setting `crossOrigin` on your local server will **FAIL** unless your server is configured to provide CORS headers.

Comment: it seems not the "crossOrigin" reason. i have upload the demo to http://edwin404.com/three/test.html . Actually i'm not very professional with 3d model software, could you please explain the "power-of-two" matter for detail? @Paul-Jan